# MassTransit.Util.Caching.GreenCache`1'

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

All of a sudden after updating the NuGet packages I am getting this exception error.

Could not load type 'MassTransit.Util.Caching.GreenCache`1' from assembly 'MassTransit, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa'.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you follow the [upgrade guide](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/upgrade-v6.html) when moving between major versions of MassTransit.